# JSON structure (algorithm point of view)

Tags: java, json, extjs

I created a loop like this :

```
JSONObject toSendBack = new JSONObject(); 
JSONArray dataArray = new JSONArray(); 

for(int i = 0 ; i < list.size() + 1 ; i++){
    JSONObject row = new JSONObject();
    for(int j = 0 ; j < 2 ; j++){ 
        if (i % 2 == 0) {
            tmp[j] = list.get(i); 
            row.put("name", tmp[j]);
        }
        else{
            tmp[j] = list.get(i); 
            row.put("description", tmp[j]); 
        }       
    }   
    dataArray.put(row); 
}

toSendBack.put("data", dataArray); 
toSendBack.put("success", true)
```

Whick give me this JSON :

```
{"data":[{"name":"Polo"},{"description":"Conso 10L"},{"name":"Polo"},{"description":"Conso 5L oil"}],"success":true}
```

How can i created this one :

```
{"data":[{"name":"Polo","description":"Conso 10L"},{"name":"Polo","description":"Conso 10L"},{"name":"Polo","description":"Conso 5L oil"}],"success":true}
```

In order to suit to my extjs-store :

```
var store = Ext.create('Ext.data.JsonStore', {
    fields : ['name', 'description'], 
    proxy : {
        type : 'memory', 
        reader : {
            type : 'json', 
            root : 'data'
        }
    }
});
```

I think it's just a loop issue.

Answer (score 0):

1. From my perspective, `tmp[j]` seems to be useless (or I need to see more of your code).
2. I don't see the point of the `for j` loop.

This should work :

```
for(int i = 0 ; i < list.size() ; i+=2){
    JSONObject row = new JSONObject();
    row.put("name", list.get(i));
    row.put("description", list.get(i+1)); 
    dataArray.put(row); 
}
```

**EDIT : fixed the answer thanks to the Mornor (OP) comments**

**EDIT by Mornor : See edit summary**

Comment: You're right about the 2 comments, but it doesn't work. I have just the "description" field in my JSON ... (because it's the only one added to the dataArray)

Comment: My bad, I didn't double checked my code ... It should be fixed now

Comment: I did something even more simple : for(int i = 0 ; i < list.size() ; i += 2){
   JSONObject row = new JSONObject(); 
   row.put("name", list.get(i));
   row.put("description", list.get(i + 1)); 
   dataArray.put(row); 
  }
Thank you !

Comment: Right. Do you want me to edit my answer with your last suggestion ?